# How to use background repeat property in angular using setElementStyle

Tags: angular

I have started working in angular 2 weeks ago . Initially I was having a question of how to set different background images for different components then a come to know that we can use setElementstyle for this and I did the same I pass the values and required fields for that but now I want that background image to be no repeat mode.

```
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-image', "url('/assets/images/background.png')");}'
```

I have use the above code in the component file to set the background image and it is working but now I want that the background image should not repeat.

Can Anyone guide me?

Comment: You are only setting `background-image`, you can also set `background-repeat` if you need it. You are not limited to one style.

Comment: Why not define a CSS selector with the required properties and use [`addClass()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#addclass) instead of `setStyle()`?

Comment: Given you've just started with angular two weeks ago you should forget about `renderer` and look at more idiomatic approaches using CSS, class bindings and maybe `:host`.